# Microsoft Band 2 + UWP + Background Task => An error occurred while attempting to acquire the Bluetooth device service

Tags: bluetooth, win-universal-app, background-task, microsoft-band

I'm writing a Windows 10 UWP app on my Surface Pro 3 which is connected to my Microsoft Band 2 and I can connect to it just fine when I'm running the app in the foreground.

But now I'm trying to use the DeviceUseTrigger and run some logic in a background task. When I call the method to connect to the band:

```
var bandInfo = (await BandClientManager.Instance.GetPairedBandsAsync()).FirstOrDefault();
var bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(bandInfo);
```

I get the following error:

> An error occurred while attempting to acquire the Bluetooth device
>   service. This error can occur if the paired device is unreachable or
>   has become unpaired from the current host.

I added the following capabilities to my UWP appxmanifest:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
<DeviceCapability Name="location" />
<DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
<DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
   <Device Id="any">
     <Function Type="serviceId:A502CA9A-2BA5-413C-A4E0-13804E47B38F" />
     <Function Type="serviceId:C742E1A2-6320-5ABC-9643-D206C677E580" />
   </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

And this is my declaration of the background task:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="WindowsRuntimeComponent1.BandBackgroundTask">
     <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="deviceUse" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
   </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but does this paragraph from the [Band SDK documentation](https://developer.microsoftband.com/Content/docs/Microsoft%20Band%20SDK.pdf) possibly help with your call of `GetPairedBandsAsync` as well?

> If your app wants to connect to the Band from the background, then the
>   app should call GetBandsAsync(isBackground: true) to get a connection
>   that will not interfere with any app that is running in the foreground
>   and currently using a Band connection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did miss that part of the documentation.

I've changed this now, but I'm still getting the same error unfortunately. Have no idea what I'm doing wrong ... :/